# CRM 2011 Comparing Lists in Advanced Find

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to use the advanced find function to find contacts that are in one marketing list but not another.

I thought I would be able to do something like:

```
     Marketing List Equals List1
 And     
     Marketing List Does Not Equal List2
```

I have done this through SQL but I want to find a way of the user doing this for themselves without me having to write a bespoke report through SSRS.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it through Advanced Find but there is workaround:

1. Create 3-rd marketing list.
2. Copy contacts from 1-st Marketing List.
3. Using Remove Based on Advanced Find option remove contacts that belong to 2-nd marketing list.